# I have one div expanding when read more is clicked, would like a close link?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have only one working, but i did the exact same to the next div and it doesnt work? Also i would like to add a close link at the bottom of the expanded content.

See my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G59nH/3/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#clickme").click(function () {
    $("#content").slideToggle("slow")
});
});
```

Comment: why are you using a link to slide a div?

Comment: The html in your fiddle is malformed.  You should consider properly indenting your code.  It makes finding issues of non-matching tags, etc. much easier to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using id's, but you cannot have multiple elements with the same id in an html document. Use classes instead, and choose which content (with the given class) to slide toggle based on proximity to the link that was clicked.

After changing the clickme and content id's to classes, you can change your js to this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".clickme").click(function () {
        $(this).closest('.servicesBox').nextAll(".content").first().slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G59nH/11/

Also notice that you have some `<div>` tags within `<p>` tags (not fixed in the fiddle), which is not technically valid syntax - would recommend replacing them with divs (if you need them at all) and adjust spacing with css as needed.

Comment: Thanks for your advice,  is there an easy way to add a close link at the bottom of the expanded content? @mayabelle

Comment: Your fiddle opens all `.content` boxes, I'm sure he just wants the one clicked on to expand?

Comment: It turns out there was HTML syntax errors, the original code has `p` tags closed outside of their containing `div`, fixing that allowed `.next('.container') to work correctly. See an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/badAdviceGuy/G59nH/9/) of your code.

Comment: @Danniellexbx - Yes, you could just call `$(this).slideToggle("slow");` assuming that your link is directly within the content div; if it's nested within another element, you can use `closest` to get to the ancestor content div before calling `slideToggle` on it.

Comment: @badAdviceGuy - I did state in my answer that there are HTML syntax errors and that they were not fixed in my modification of the original fiddle. However you were right, I was missing `.first()` in my original answer - now fixed. Thanks!

Comment: Ideally you would clean up the html to have the `servicesBox` and `content` divs direct siblings of each other, then you can just do this: `$(this).closest('.servicesBox').next(".content").slideToggle("slow");`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that in your HTML, you have got two elements with the same id (in your case, 'clickme' and 'content'). The statement

```
$('#clickme')
```

Is used as a listener to the element with the id defined after the '#'. So in your case, you tell it to listen for a click on the element with the 'clickme' id. But as you have two of them, only one will work. What you want is to give them the same class (for example, 'clickme'). If you use the class listeners

```
$('.clickme')
```

and

```
$('.content')
```

it should work fine. To distinguish which element was clicked, you can use the index of the clicked 'clickme' element:

```
$('.clickme').click(function(){

    var index = $('.clickme').index(this);
    $('.content').eq(index).slideToggle();
});
```